# What is the difference between the different builds?

Tags: ember.js

I noticed when building Ember.js and more recently in the new Builds page on [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/release) that there are "normal", "runtime" and "prod" builds.

What is the difference between each and when should we use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not absolutely sure, but here is a guess that i am quite confident of:

There are 2 dimensions to this question: Runtime vs Normal and Prod vs Non-Prod

**Runtime vs Normal**: Runtime is a only a subset of the normal (complete) ember distribution, which contains only the object system. I guess this is included, because people asked for it from time to time. A quote of a core contributor (found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947156/overview-of-the-ember-js-code)):

> Runtime provides the Ember object system along with a handful of
>   useful classes. The object system is built with many of the
>   foundational technologies implemented in metal, but exposes them in a
>   much cleaner way to the application developer.

**Prod vs Non-Prod:** As you can see on the builds page the prod build is a little bit smaller, so it is missing some lines of code. I am pretty sure that **those missing lines are assertions that are stripped from the ember build as they are needed only development and can slow down your application considerably.**

Comment: this was clearly faster than me :) you caught me being in the editor ;)

Comment: :-D Thought you must be sleeping or something, since this one had still no answer :-D

Comment: hahaha :) I was teaching my little daughter (2 years old) some basic javascript and of course talking about ember.js ;)